# Migrate/Copy VM from ESXi to other ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi, migration

I am attempting to migrate a lot of VMs from old ESXi server to new ESXi server

I don't have VMware vCenter

I have Veeam Backup and Replication

Any idea or any suggestions to do this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enable SSH on both hosts
2. Enable outgoing SSH connections in the firewall on the source host
3. Shutdown the VM
4. Connect to the source host via ssh
5. Copy the VM with scp to the target host
6. Register the VM on the target host
7. Start the VM on the target host
8. Delete the VM on the source host

Comment: How to copy the vm ? which folder ?

Comment: The datastores are mounted in `/vmfs/volumes/`

Comment: the file cannot copy fully with scp
i have a file with 20Gb , scp can copy only 550 kb !

Comment: that's not true. There is no size limit for scp. I have used this method lots of times.

Comment: scp "VM Mailcatcher.vmdk" user@192.168.88.22:/vmfs/volumes/datastore1/Mailcatcher

this is my command

Comment: Well, that would be a new question. It can't be solved in comments, and it can't be solved without actual error messages.

Comment: what is the error in my command ? can you correct my commande please ?

Comment: There is no error in your command (except that I would rather copy whole directories recursively instead of every file one by one). If you provided the error message you get (in a new question) we might be able to find the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [VMware Converter](https://www.vmware.com/products/converter.html) to migrate the VMs.

1. Download and install the VMware Converter Standalone (It's free)
2. Click on *Convert machine*
3. Connect to your source ESXi
4. Select your (powered off) VM
5. Select the target ESXi
6. (Optional: Make any necessary changes to the virtual hardware)
7. Start the conversion

Comment: Sorry for not suggesting this in the first place. I dismissed it earlier because you stated that you don't have vCenter licensed. I somehow thought that the converter is bundled with vCenter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Veeam replication](https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/vsphere/replica_job.html?ver=95u4) for this scenario, but be aware that unlicensed ESXi is not supported.